# Is there a way to access IBM cloud watson personality insights service now(19.12.2020)?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, personality-insights, watson-personality-insights

I am trying to access [IBM Watson Personality Insight](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/watson-personality-insights) service through the [IBM Cloud Catalog](https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog) but it does not show up there.

In the [Personality Insight Documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/personality-insights?code=python) it is stated that this service will not be available from 1 December 2021 but I cannot access it now.

I tried to complete [Get started with AI development by using the Personality Insights service](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/architecture/tutorials/personality-insights/) but links to the Personality Insight services redirects to [IBM Cloud Catalog](https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog) or [Watson Natural Language Understanding](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/watson-natural-language-understanding)

I tried to access the service via IBM Cloud CLI on my machine but it does not show up there also.
I just need to access the service to create API key for my application.

Is there anyone can help me to access this service?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message in the [docs for Personality Insights](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/personality-insights?topic=personality-insights-about) says that is deprecated since December 1st, 2020. It is available until December 2021 if you already have an instance of it. In that latter case, you could always create new credentials or service bindings and it should be listed under [your resources](https://cloud.ibm.com/resources).

Comment: Thank you for your answer to clarify the situation. Unfortunately, I didn't have this service in my resources. May you suggest a similar product/service to the Watson Personality Insight? I searched for [Watson Natural Language Understanding](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/natural-language-understanding?topic=natural-language-understanding-about) but I could not figure out how to adapt this system to use in a way that Personality Insight service does.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any experience, but hope my answer is correct. Please mark as answered and upvote.

Comment: Sorry, I could not upvote since I have not got enough reputation. Thanks again.